# react calling a function in a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to call a function that is stored in a child component form the parent. But not sure to to do it. I know if were form child to parent I could simply use the component props but not sure how to do it from parent to child.

as you can see form the below example the button in the parent class need to trigger the display function in the child class.

```
var Parent = React.createClass ({
   render() {
       <Button onClick={child.display} ?>
   } 
})


var Child = React.createClass ({
    getInitialState () {
        return {
            display: true
        };
    },


    display: function(){
        this.setState({
             display: !this.state.display
        })
    },

    render() {
     {this.state.display}
    } 
})
```

Comment: How do you define them as parent and child if `Parent` never renders `Child`?

Comment: I just wrote a basic example up there, my actual code does render the child.

Comment: @chinds there is a good answer below, but it would be helpful if you could edit your example code so that it **does** include the Child component. Presumably, replacing Button with Child will do the trick.

This would make it easier for people to understand both the problem and the suggested answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is through using `refs`(See [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)).

```
var Parent = React.createClass ({

   triggerChildDisplay: function() {
       this.refs.child.display();
   },

   render() {
       <Button onClick={this.triggerChildDisplay} />
   } 
})


var Child = React.createClass ({
    getInitialState () {
        return {
            display: true
        };
    },


    display: function(){
        this.setState({
             display: !this.state.display
        })
    },

    render() {
     {this.state.display}
    } 
})
```

I basically copied in your example, but do note that in your Parent, I don't see you render a Child component, but typically, you would, and on that Child you would give it a ref, like `<Child ref="child" />`.

Comment: Thnk you, this is exactly what I was after.

Comment: Keep in mind that while refs may be set up as props in `render()`, you wont be able to access their values in that method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to call a child function from a parent component.

For this use case there is a better way to achieve this result and that is by setting the 'display' property of the child component to the value of a prop passed to it by the parent, eg.

```
var Parent = React.createClass ({
    getInitialState() {
        return {displayChild: false};
    },

    toggleChildDisplay() {
        this.setState({
            displayChild: !this.state.displayChild
        });
    },

    render() {
        <Button onClick={this.toggleChildDisplay} />
        <Child display={this.state.displayChild} />
    }
});

var Child = React.createClass ({
    render: function() {
        if (this.props.display) {
            /*return component*/
        } else {
            /*Don't render*/
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It is possible, see my answer.